# How to directly get Students list using Spring data jpa @Query annotation

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two entities: Group and Student which is ManyToMany relation, Group is the owner。

Now define a GroupRepository extends from JpaRepository and want to declare a method using @Query annotation to directly get Student list given a GroupId. How?

The method return value should be List or Page, just no idea how to define using query language.

I know how to get a Group entity with eagerly fetch all Students with that Group like below:

```
@Query("select group from Group group left join fetch group.students where group.id=:id")
Group findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Very appreciated for any help.

Comment: Can you put your entity classes Group and Student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model like this:

```java
@Entity
class Group {

   @Id Ling id;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   private List<Student> students;

   //...
}

@Entity
class Student {

   @Id Long id;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
   private List<Group> groups;

   //...
}
```

Then to get all students through the group repo you can make a method like this:

```java
interface GroupRepo extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {
    @Query("select s from Group g join g.students s where g.id = ?1")
    Page<Student> getAllStudentsByGroupId(Long groupId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Sources: [1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional), [2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join).